# how to move a table view cell from one table view to a new table view

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, xcode, uitableview

Currently, I am trying to move a tableview cell from one table view to another. I can't seem to get the proper mechanics down and need help with this task.

Right now I have an array that is not filled with any goals for my progress table view cells.

```
    var goals: [String] = []
```

Here is the setup for the rest of this progress table view.

```
extension ViewController: UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return goals[section].count
    }

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "TodayGoalViewCell_1", for: indexPath) as? GoalTableViewCell
        cell?.goalLabel.text = goals[indexPath.section][indexPath.row]
        cell?.cellDelegate = self
        cell?.index = indexPath
        return cell!
}
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? {
    return sections[section]
}

func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return goals.count
}
```

In a separate file I have another table view that is already filled with goals. Here is the code:

```
var goals = ["goal 1", "goal 2", "goal 3"]

extension GoalsViewController: UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return Goals.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "GoalConversationsCell_1", for: indexPath)
        cell.textLabel?.text = Goals[indexPath.row]
        cell.textLabel?.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakMode.byWordWrapping
        cell.textLabel?.numberOfLines = 3
        return cell
    }


    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        if indexPath.section == 0 {
            Goals.remove(at: indexPath.row)
            Goals.count != 0 {
                showGoalSelected()
            } else {
                Goals.append(contentsOf: theEmptyModel)
            }
            tableView.reloadData()
        }
    }
}
```

I would like to make it so that when a user selects a goal from the table view which already had goals, that these goals are moved to the progress table view. How would I do this?

Comment: Just to be clear, the text are in a button? why not just use the cell's textlabel should be enough for what you need. To capture the tap why not listen to the didSelect delegate of tableview?

Comment: your goals array is a one dimensional array. But you use it in tableview delegate methods as a two dimensional array.

Answer (score 0):

If there is a button inside your cell and you want to get news when this button is clicked, you need to look at the ***protocol-delegate*** pattern.

But you can also try to remove the button inside the cell and use a text label. To use the ***didSelectRowAt*** method to catch clicking on cell, tableView in delegete.

I do not know what kind of design and structure you have, I just offer you perspective.

Comment: Another approach is implementing an UIBarbuttonitem with plus icon, it will stick to your navigation bar all the time, then listen to its event like a normal button.

Comment: how would I implement the didSelectRowAt method?